# How to find recursive substring in Bash using Regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

My string look like

```
str1="The ID of ABC=98766 --,the ID of BCD=12345 --, the ID of XYZ=72819 --"
```

My approach to find substring

```
re='(^|ID)([^---])(.*)'
remaining=$str1
while [[ $remaining =~ $re ]];
do
...

done
```

Expected Output

```
ID of ABC=98766 --
ID of BCD=12345 --
ID of XYZ=72819 --
```

I am using Regex but can't find the proper combination of Posix Character class

Comment: By default RE is greedy - finds the biggest match on the line. It can be convinced to be non-greedy. In simple cases I use negative rules like you tried to do, bsometimes that is not possible. I have a feeling that is '.*?'  but you need to read up on non-greedy matching :-)

Comment: Your phrase `[^---]` doesn't do what you think it does. It says "match anything that is not" `-` `-` or `-`, or it means "match anything that is not between" `-` and `-` , which is quite a strange request either way!

Comment: Bash regex matching (`=~`) is always greedy but there are sometimes tricks that can be used to limit that. But there is no non-greedy operator or modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` you may use:

```
grep -Po '\bID .*? --' <<< "$str1"
```

```
ID of ABC=98766 --
ID of BCD=12345 --
ID of XYZ=72819 --
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `ID`: Match text `ID`
- `.*?` followed by 0 or more of 0 or more characters
- `--`: Match `" --"`

To populate an array:

```
readarray -t arr < <(grep -Po '\bID .*? --' <<< "$str1")
```

Check array contents:

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="ID of ABC=98766 --" [1]="ID of BCD=12345 --" [2]="ID of XYZ=72819 --")
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/W5jRbP)

Comment: and if we need to store each line in array then?

Comment: How can I help for writing `Its not working`? What exactly is not working?

Comment: It is storing complete string str1 in arr[0] only and a[1], a[2] are blank

Comment: I have updated my answer and also added a working code demo link.